# Get current / computed style of an HtmlElement in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

I need to get the current calculated style of element in winform webrowser.

get the element:
`HtmlElement em = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("theIdOfElement");`

now to get the style i can use: 
`var style = em.Style`
or 
`var style = em.GetAttribute("style");`

the documentation says that the style property "**Gets or sets a semicolon-delimited list of styles for the current element.**"
so the result should look something like:
"font-weight:bold"

But the result i get in first case is "null" and in second its "System.__ComObject"
From what i understand, if the style is in html for example :

`<div id ="myId" style="color:red" </div>`

than the result is "color:red" but when the div style is affected by CSS than the result is null.

Is there a way to get the current style of Htmlelemnt even if the style is only in CSS file ?

If i cant get the current style is there any other way to determinate if the htmlelement is visible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` property returns the value that you have explicitly assigned to `style`.

To get the computed style, you can use [`currentStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/currentStyle) property of `element` or [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method of the `window`.

The following code get computed `background-color` and computed `color` for an `a` element:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a {background-color:red;}
        </style>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id='a1' href='#' style='color:yellow;'>Test</a>
    </body>
</html>";

webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (obj, arg) =>
{
    dynamic element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("a1").DomElement;
    var style = element.currentStyle;

    // OR
    // dynamic window = webBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow;
    // var style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);

    var backColor = style.backgroundColor;
    var color = style.color;
};
```

Comment: Yes this is what i needed! Works like a charm, thank you kind sir !